# Learn Markup Validation

Tags: php, html

So from the (very little) that I've read about Markup Validation, it's basically just a grammar/spelling check.  However, I can't find any sources on how to make "good" HTML code.  Is there any site in which I can learn how to write HTML properly?

Here's my code that was called horrid (specifically the HTML).

```
<html>
<title>MySQL Search!</title>
<body>
<p>Search Results:</p>
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr>
<th>Card Name</th>
<th>Mana Cost</th>
<th>Card Set</th>
<th>Ability</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';
$Checkbox = $_POST['Ability'];
$q="SELECT * FROM mtgcards WHERE Ability LIKE '%$Checkbox%'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Mana Cost'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Colour'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Set'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . $row['Ability'] . "</td>";
    Echo "<td>" . '<img style="display:block" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['Image']) . '" width="100%" height="100%" /></td>';
    Echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is a good starting point.

Comment: It'll be hard to validate your html When it's with php. You must run your page on the server, copy the page's source code and check it in the [w3c  Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) or in a similer website.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf, OK, I won't ask people to validate.  But I still do want to get sent in the right direction to find help with markups.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: There are a number of problems with your code: mixing logic and presentation, SQL injection vulnerability, and others. One reason your HTML doesn't validate is that you have no opening `<tr>` tag in your while loop, only a closing `</tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need look into [Web template system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system)

[image]

It is considered messy to mix `PHP` and `HTML` like you did in your post.

And it will get worse as your web app grows.

There are many ones for `PHP`, one of the most popular ones is [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) and [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

You can also [create your own](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/roll-your-own-templating-system-in-php--net-16596).

**The bigger issue here is that you are not using prepared statements, you should be using [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to execute your queries.**